# Wait For Response Before Continuing - Like Prompt()

Tags: javascript

I have a function that relies on a confirm.js prompt input. I want the function to wait for the input to be fulfilled prior to continuing anymore. In the same way prompt() waits for the ok button to be pressed, I want my function to wait for a button click event before it returns and proceeds.

Right now I attempted a Promise (not familiar at all):

```js
function dostuff(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.confirm({
            content: '<input id="input">',
            buttons: {
                done: {
                    text: 'Done',
                    action: () => {
                        resolve(); // resolve promise when button is pressed
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }).then(function(){
      return input.val();
    });
  }
}
```

But using the function doesn't pause the execution of the remaining script.
For example:

```js
console.log("start")
dostuff().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
console.log("end")
```

Will print:

```
start
end
undefined
```

Then finally the input value once I've pressed enter.

Comment: `prompt()` is a badly designed native function. You **don't want** to stop the execution of the entire script. And it's not impossible to implement this for yourself.

Comment: Simply move the remaining script (`console.log("end")`) inside the `.then()` callback, after the `console.log(result);`.